# Wordpress Ultimate Popup Plugin - Keep modal open even when clicked outside of?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [Ultimate Popup Plugin from CodeCanyon](https://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-popup-wordpress/13011293) on this website [Click here](http://betawholesale.wholesaleautousa.com/) to create a login modal.

The code is working fine, but the popup stays even if someone clicks outside the popup, and the user must enter the details and click enter.

[This](http://prntscr.com/iuvd0n) is how it looks;

I tried providing a z-index to keep the popup on but I am stuck.

I had updated the code I have for the wordpress plugin whatever I could find.

This is the CSS and the JS of the popup:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if (jQuery.cookie("popupTemporaryCookie13428")) {
 
        // Popup is hiding after showing first time!
        jQuery("#ultimate-popup-13428").hide();
 
    } else if (jQuery.cookie("popupLongerCookie13428")) {
   
        var inst = jQuery("#ultimate-popup-13428").remodal();
        inst.open();
   
        jQuery("#ultimate-popup-13428").addClass("ultimate-popup-wrapper-activate");
       
    } else {
   
        var inst = jQuery("#ultimate-popup-13428").remodal();
        inst.open();
 
   
        jQuery("#ultimate-popup-13428").addClass("ultimate-popup-wrapper-activate");
       
    }
       
     
 
    var expiresAt = new Date();
    expiresAt.setTime(expiresAt.getTime() + 1*24*60*60*1000); // Days
    jQuery.cookie("popupLongerCookie13428", new Date());
    jQuery.cookie("popupTemporaryCookie13428", true, { expires: expiresAt }); 
   
});
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *:before,
    *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-wrapper {
        background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-top: 8px solid;
        padding: 35px;
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 9999;
        opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
                transition: .4s;
        visibility: hidden;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-wrapper-activate {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100);
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .cross-btn-ppm {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        z-index: 99;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-inner h2,
    .entry-content .ultimate-popup-inner h2,
    .entry-summary .ultimate-popup-inner h2,
    .page-content .ultimate-popup-inner h2,
    .comment-content .ultimate-popup-inner h2 {
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        word-wrap: normal;
        -webkit-hyphens: none;
        -moz-hyphens: none;
        -ms-hyphens: none;
            hyphens: none;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-inner {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes p {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes input[type="text"],
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes input[type="email"] {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes {
        margin: 30px auto 0;
        max-width: 500px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes br { display: none }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes input[type="submit"] {
        border: medium none;
        border-radius: 7px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
                transition: .4s;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes .gform_wrapper .gform_heading { display: none }
    .ultimate-popup-shortcodes .gform_wrapper .gform_footer {
        margin: 15px 0 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-wrapper-hide .lean-overlay,
    .ultimate-popup-wrapper-hide .ultimate-popup-wrapper {
        display: none !important;
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-2 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-3 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-4 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-8 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-9 .cross-btn-ppm {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-2 .cross-btn-ppm { top: -8px }
    .ultimate-popup-theme-id-5.ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate .cross-btn-ppm {
        background: #333;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        top: 20px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-theme-id-5.ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate .popup-inner-col-thumb { padding-top: 5px }
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-12 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-10 .cross-btn-ppm,
    .ultimate-popup-halfway-scroll-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-6 .cross-btn-ppm {
        right: 10px;
        top: 5px;
    }
    .ultimate-popup-theme-id-1 .cross-btn-ppm { right: 10px }
     
     
     
     
    /* Mobile Layout: 320px. */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .ultimate-popup-wrapper { overflow: auto }
        .ultimate-popup-wrapper .pop-inner-column .popup-inner-col-thumb {
            float: none;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: auto;
        }
        .ultimate-popup-wrapper .pop-inner-column .popup-inner-col-cont {
            float: none;
            padding: 25px;
            width: auto;
        }
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate .cross-btn-ppm,
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-2 .cross-btn-ppm,
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-3 .cross-btn-ppm,
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-4 .cross-btn-ppm,
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-8 .cross-btn-ppm,
        .ultimate-popup-automatic-activate.ultimate-popup-theme-id-9 .cross-btn-ppm {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 99;
            border-radius: 0;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal"
  data-remodal-options="hashTracking: false, closeOnOutsideClick: false">
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Login</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required id="pwd" name="pwd">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enter</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you want the popup to stay even if they click the overlay?

Comment: you need to show the code as well, nobody is going to surf through your site for it, post the PHP ode you use or js code you use to initialize the popup

Comment: problem is i am using wordpress plugin, and the plugin is not offering any additional information but let me see if i get something here: This is the css of the popup: `https://www.pastebin.ca/4004843` and this one is the javascript code: `https://pastebin.ca/4004846`

Comment: are you creating that JS, or is the plugin? if it's using [remodal](https://github.com/vodkabears/Remodal) (which it looks like it is, per [this js file in your source](view-source:http://betawholesale.wholesaleautousa.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-popup/assets/js/remodal.min.js), depending on the version, you can specify options in the html. specifically, you'd want to change `closeOnOutsideClick` to false

Comment: the one i am showing you is coming from the plugin, i did not wrote my own

Comment: no such luck with the data-remodal options?

Comment: nopes, it  does not d o anything

Comment: "but the popup stays even if someone clicks outside the popup" and "I tried providing a z-index to keep the popup on but I am stuck." are **contradictory**. You say that it stays open even if users click outside, but you try to keep it open. Which one is it?

Comment: It does not stay open if click outside of the popup, and that is what i want i want it to stay on top unless user enters username/password, no esc command or click anywhere should close it